# Is there a good way to start programs from gvim without losing focus?

Tags: vim

Vim has a built-in way for executing programs, namely `:!start foo` for Windows and `:!bar &` for Unix. However, the problem I have with those is that they steal focus from Vim. I'd like to launch my build & test script, and while its working and showing output in its command window never have to manually switch back to GVim.

I have thought of 3 possible solutions:

- Use Auto-It/AutoHotkey to set focus back to Gvim. Unfortunately that only works in Windows and it's brittle.
- Have another process watching my sourcecode, and let that process automatically launch the script when the sourecode changes. (Another process creating a new window does not steal focus). This is a bit gimmicky, as you need to hold off on writing files until you want to start the script, and sometimes write a useless change if you want to re-test even though nothing in the source changed.
- Use a client-server architecture, where Vim sends the command over a socket or something similar. This is actually my preferred solution, if there is any existing cross-platform way to do it. (I would prefer not having an extra GVim instance running for this though.)

So what would be a good way to do this? I have tried [AsyncCommander](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3431) but unfortunately it also steals focus.

Comment: Have you tried to change the settings of your Window Manager, so that it does not give focus to newly created windows?

Comment: I have never heard of `:start`. My gvim 7.3 doesn't support it.

Comment: @DidierTrosset That's a pretty clever idea, but it should not work all the time like this (giving focus to new windows, even created from Vim, is usually what I want).

Comment: @sehe Whoops, my bad, it was supposed to be `:!start`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I'm not using a nice build system like `sbt` that watches source code and re-builds/re-tests for me, I tend to come up with hacks like this:

```
 :map <F9> :!touch and-go<CR><CR>
```

Here hitting `F9` updates a file. Pick any key binding you like.
(and of course you could do the same with `imap` for vim's insert mode as well.)

Then all one needs is a shell script that watches this file and executes the 
command that builds/tests your project. On unix, I'd just do:

```
 while stat -c "%Y" and-go; do sleep 1; done | 
 stdbuf -i0 -o0 uniq -c | 
 while read l; do 
    echo build...;  # Your build/test execution commands here.
 done
```

Running that in a separate window will be neat, because your vim/gvim window will retain it's focus throughout, while you just keep hitting `F9` (or whatever) and glancing at this other window to see how your build went.

If you're up to writing a windows batch script (or powershell, I don't know) version of that as well, you should be good to go.

Comment: This is a pretty decent solution, and more clever than the solution I proposed myself. The only thing I dislike is that it is polling and not portable. Isn't there any better way to do something like this than 'rolling your own'?

Comment: Yeah, too bad about the polling. The way I see it, if you want to keep focus while kicking off another build/test script - you'll want the build/test script running in another window. And that implies that something needs to start it on some signal from you (from `vim`). I usually prefer small scripts than GUI applications.

Comment: I believe this is the best option at the moment, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

```
:silent! !cmd /c start /b dir
```

Also, `start.exe` does have an option to start minimized instead of with the shared/background console.

Of course, `dir` is to be replaced :)

Comment: Unfortunately when I don't use the minimize option the focus is still lost, and it is important to be able to see the results.

Comment: Erm. Perhaps you should just make the vim window "Always On Top" with one of the many many utilities that do this.

Comment: That would be possible, but the question is not about being "Always On Top" but keeping focus. It could be done with autohotkey but that seems hacky and not portable.

Comment: @Daan Yah, I know. Trying to be helpful. Also, this is not about portability. No thing that involves window placement will ever be portable. I'm afraid you'll find all solutions are bound to stay hacky. **PS** look at [`screen`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen), though, I think you can 'send' commands to be run in an existing screen session.